# Using python to search on a website and return results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to build a program that searches the expiry date of a vehicle, however when I do my post request nothing happens and I'm not getting data.

I'm putting the vehicle registration in this website: https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry

and it redirects to me to the below link with the results

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9dU.png)

Could someone please help me.

The current code I have is:

```
import requests
my_url = 'https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry'

s = requests.session()

s.get(my_url)

data = {'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-type' :  'car/truck' ,
'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-identifier-type' :  'registration number' ,
'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown' : 'abc123'        
        }

result = requests.post(my_url, data = data)

print(result)
```

Comment: From "Terms and conditions": _You must not access this website and services in any way that could impact or disrupt the service, or lead to unauthorised disclosure of information. This includes data mining activity via software or other automatic devices to access, monitor or copy this service or its contents without written permission to do so by VicRoads._ Do you have written permission?

Comment: I would recommend web scraping with `selenium` as the there is a redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Basically you haven't sent all required `POST` parameters to the `HOST` as you can see within your `Print-Screen` there's multiple parameters with values.

Now, we will make a `GET` request to parse the `HTML` and getting all required values and then make a `POST` request.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
    'site-search-head': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PersonalEmail$EmailAddress': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PersonalPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$OrganisationEmail$EmailAddress': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$OrganisationPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PartnerEmail$EmailAddress': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PartnerPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-type': 'car/truck',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-identifier-type': 'registration+number',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown': 'abc123',
    'honeypot': '',
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$btnSearch': 'Search'
}


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        data['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get("value")
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.findAll("div", class_="display"))


Main("https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry")
```

Now, if you did checked the output, you will see it's empty, that's due two things.

1. there's a value called `monsido` within the `HTML` source which is used with `JS` to generate a `one-time` token to authenticate the request during the session.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _monsido = _monsido || [];
    _monsido.push(['_setDomainToken', 'dfWhFzGbaTj5hyKQYZxi0g']);
    _monsido.push(['_withStatistics', 'true']);
</script>
<script src="//cdn.monsido.com/tool/javascripts/monsido.js"></script>
<script>
```

2. the `HOST` is protected with `CloudFlare` where it's requiring a `__cfduid` parameter within the `Cookie` as well.

Now, to shorten the road, indeed if you called monsido under the `requests.Session()` with the current `cookies/headers`, you will get the token required. so you will now need to get `__cfduid` which i couldn't help you with that as it's count illegal to bypass known firewall such as that, which is actually invented to prevent such cases of scraping.

Now, moving back to `selenium` , you can get your desired output:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry")
regnum = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "input#ph_pagebody_0_phthreecolumnmaincontent_1_panel_VehicleSearch_RegistrationNumberCar_RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown").send_keys("abc123")
click = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "input#ph_pagebody_0_phthreecolumnmaincontent_1_panel_btnSearch").click()

names = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("label.label")]
data = [item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    "div.display")[:10]]

df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=names)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c72048bc2dd9ce8b9f323325bec4b193/data.csv)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Long story short:** CORS policy: No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header is present on the requested resource.

**JS Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/registration/buy-sell-or-transfer-a-vehicle/check-vehicle-registration/vehicle-registration-enquiry",
    data: data,
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Doing the POST request within the page using JavaScript, results in the expected response, a page showing the following:

> Registration check
>   Results for abc123 as at 29/03/2020 18:05 AEDT
>   Registration number:
>   ABC123
>   Registration status & expiry date:
>   Current - 26/03/2021
>   Vehicle:
>   2013 SILVER ISUZU DC UTE
>   VIN/Chassis:
>   MPATFS85JDT005836
>   Engine number:
>   LB8052
>   Registration serial number:
>   2276051
>   Compliance plate date:
>   07/2013
>   Sanction(s) applicable:
>   None
>   Goods carrying vehicle:
>   Yes
>   Transfer in dispute:
>   No
>   Download report PDF

However, doing the request from outside the website will get a CORS policy: No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' error. Performing the request from Python will not necessarily give that error, but will result in the wrong response, which is the one you are getting. Also, the data for the request should include all these:

```
data = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',  
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',  
    '__VIEWSTATE': {TOO LONG TO BE POSTED},  
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '3ECD7CB5',  
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',  
    'site-search-head': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PersonalEmail$EmailAddress': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PersonalPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',   
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$OrganisationEmail$EmailAddress': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$OrganisationPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PartnerEmail$EmailAddress': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phheader_0$_FlyoutLogin$PartnerPassword$SingleLine_CtrlHolderDivShown': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-type': 'car/truck',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$vehicle-identifier-type': 'registration number',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$VehicleSearch$RegistrationNumberCar$RegistrationNumber_CtrlHolderDivShown': 'abc123',  
    'honeypot': '',  
    'ph_pagebody_0$phthreecolumnmaincontent_1$panel$btnSearch': 'Search'  
}
```

**Follow the instructions here to get the one missing (`__VIEWSTATE`):**

https://mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/

Comment: even if he got the `__VIEWSTATE`, you will not get a valid response.

Comment: You MUST read the answer carefully. The only way of getting the "valid response" is by doing the the request from WITHIN THE WEBSITE ***AND*** sending the correct data.

Comment: so you are just telling the `OP` to use the browser to get the desired data? is it really considered as answer in your opinion?

Comment: Be *INFORMED* that I've read the answer, am asking you _once again_ , where is the real answer? let's say i would like to use your answer to achieve the desired output. !